# Github Probot: why are pinned issues treated as style and marked as wont_fix?

Tags: github, probot

Using Probot on Github and it is configured like this:

```
exemptLabels:
  - pinned
  - security
# Label to use when marking an issue as stale
staleLabel: wontfix
...
```

yet Probot marks pinned issue as "stale" ([example](https://github.com/andig/evcc/issues/2)). The issue does not have an explicit "pinned" label though?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is simply not supported and has caused confusion before: https://github.com/probot/stale/issues/192